# R loading 3-line per row text file as 3-column data frame

Tags: r, transform, dataframe

I've got an input file like this:

```
/tmp/file-16
31361
999
/tmp/file-38
5673
413
/tmp/file-118
7210
450
/tmp/file-105
140910
2117
/tmp/file-76
25857
956
/tmp/file-99
34416
774
/tmp/file-48
21
22
/tmp/file-77
117652
1397
/tmp/file-197
33448
1057
```

That I want to load in R turning it into a 3-column data frame where every 3 lines will become a row like this:

```
/tmp/file-16 31361 999 
/tmp/file-38 5673 413 
/tmp/file-118 7210 450 
/tmp/file-105 140910 2117 
/tmp/file-76 25857 956 
/tmp/file-99 34416 774 
/tmp/file-48 21 22 
/tmp/file-77 117652 1397 
/tmp/file-197 33448 1057
```

I need to plot the numbers in R anyway, so the shortest would be to do the transformation in R. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read a text file into R when the data is not in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422949/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-r-when-the-data-is-not-in-a-table)

Comment: You might be right, although I didn't think so at first.

Comment: You don't need `sep="\n"` though. This works: `inp <- as.data.frame(scan(File, what=list(one="", two=0L, three=0L)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach. It makes use of the `what` parameter, which can be passed a `list` to read `multi-line` records. Here is an extract of the relevant documentation.

> **what:** the type of what gives the type of data to be read. The supported
>   types are logical, integer, numeric, complex, character, raw and list.
>   If what is a list, it is assumed that the lines of the data file are
>   records each containing length(what) items (‘fields’) and the list
>   components should have elements which are one of the first six types
>   listed or NULL

```
y <- data.frame(scan('test.txt', 
 what = list(a = 'character', b = 'character', c = 'character')))

              a      b    c
1  /tmp/file-16  31361  999
2  /tmp/file-38   5673  413
3 /tmp/file-118   7210  450
4 /tmp/file-105 140910 2117
5  /tmp/file-76  25857  956
6  /tmp/file-99  34416  774
7  /tmp/file-48     21   22
8  /tmp/file-77 117652 1397
9 /tmp/file-197  33448 1057
```

Comment: looks like your example returns the numeric data as a `factor`. I don't think this is what the OP wanted. Perhaps using "numeric" for `b` and `c` or `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the call to `data.frame` with a further change of the data.type for the last two columns will be suitable. (the same problem applies to my answer if handing over the matrix to `as.data.frame` without further processing)

Comment: The problem with that use of scan was identified by @Joshua.Ulrich in my answer (and I fixed my answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your data is in a file called `test.txt`, then you can use `scan()` to read the data line by line and use a suitable command to transform it in tabular form as you wish:

```
tmp <- scan("test.txt", "character")
tmp2 <- matrix(tmp, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

The `matrix()` command with `byrow = TRUE` will return it in a sutiable format:

```
      [,1]            [,2]     [,3]  
 [1,] "/tmp/file-16"  "31361"  "999" 
 [2,] "/tmp/file-38"  "5673"   "413" 
 [3,] "/tmp/file-118" "7210"   "450" 
 [4,] "/tmp/file-105" "140910" "2117"
 [5,] "/tmp/file-76"  "25857"  "956" 
 [6,] "/tmp/file-99"  "34416"  "774" 
 [7,] "/tmp/file-48"  "21"     "22"  
 [8,] "/tmp/file-77"  "117652" "1397"
 [9,] "/tmp/file-197" "33448"  "1057"
```

Make sure to use `as.data.frame()` and `as.numeric()` before you use the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines <- readLines(file)
newtext <- paste(lines[seq(1, length(lines)-2, by=3)],
      lines[seq(2, length(lines)-1, by=3)], 
      lines[seq(3, length(lines), by=3)]) # space is the default separator
dfrm <- read.table(textConnection(newtext))
```

I didn't think Joshua was correct in saying that my earlier answer was applicable, but it turned out to be even more general than I realized.

```
> scan(textConnection(lines), what=list(fil="char", N1 = 0, N2 = 0))
Read 9 records
$fil
[1] "/tmp/file-16"  "/tmp/file-38"  "/tmp/file-118" "/tmp/file-105"
[5] "/tmp/file-76"  "/tmp/file-99"  "/tmp/file-48"  "/tmp/file-77" 
[9] "/tmp/file-197"

$N1
[1]  31361   5673   7210 140910  25857  34416     21 117652  33448

$N2
[1]  999  413  450 2117  956  774   22 1397 1057
```

So `as.data.frame()` on that result would also give a solution.

Comment: `what` needs to be a bit different though, since the _type_ of `what` is what matters: `what=list(fil="", N1=0, N2=0)`.  Perhaps you're confusing it with the `colClasses` argument to `read.table` et al?