# How do I read a text file into R when each record is a paragraph and some records have 4 fields and others have 6

Tags: r

How can one read in a text file in which each record is a paragraph and each newline denotes separate field. The complication is that some records have 4 lines and some have 6. @DWin nailed my questions when the the difference in number of fields was 1 but it all fell apart when it was two. You can have a [look at his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423131/168139).

So here is my latest simulation of the starting text

```
TheInstitute 5467
  telephone line 4125526987 x 4567
  datetime 2011110516 12:56
  blay blay blah who knows what, but anyway it may have a comma

TheInstitute 5467
  telephone line 4125526987 x 4567
  datetime 2011110516 12:58
  blay blay blah who knows what

TheInstitute 5467
  telephone line 412552999 x 4999
  bump phone line 4125527777
  bump pony pony oops 4125527777
  datetime 2011110516 12:59
  blay blay blah who knows what

TheInstitute 5467
  telephone line 4125526987 x 4567
  bump phone line 4125527777
  bump pony pony oops 4125527777
  datetime 2011110516 13:51
  blay blay blah who knows what, but anyway it may have a comma

TheInstitute 5467
  telephone line 4125526987 x 4567
  datetime 2011110516 14:56
  blay blay blah who knows what
```

Here is what the output should look like. In fact this is one step removed from what I need. I am placing a ASCII text representation of an R data.frame below. You will see that everything is in a data frame but the field values are shifted by two columns because some records have two extra fields.

```
structure(list(institution = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "TheInstitute 5467", class = "factor"), 
    telephoneline = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("telephone line 4125526987 x 4567", 
    "telephone line 412552999 x 4999"), class = "factor"), date.or.bump = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("bump phone line 4125527777", 
    "datetime 2011110516 12:56", "datetime 2011110516 12:58", 
    "datetime 2011110516 14:56"), class = "factor"), field4 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("blay blay blah who knows what", 
    "blay blay blah who knows what, but anyway it may have a comma", 
    "bump pony pony oops 4125527777"), class = "factor"), field5 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "datetime 2011110516 12:59", 
    "datetime 2011110516 13:51"), class = "factor"), field6 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "blay blay blah who knows what", 
    "blay blay blah who knows what, but anyway it may have a comma"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("institution", "telephoneline", 
"date.or.bump", "field4", "field5", "field6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

PS: Am I correct to believe that one posts a data frame by using dput or can one save a .Rdata file direclty here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way, but this should get the job done.

```
x <- readLines("foo.txt")  # read data with readLines
nx <- !nchar(x)            # locate lines with only empty strings
# create a list (split by empty lines, with empty lines removed)
y <- split(x[!nx], cumsum(nx)[!nx])
# determine largest number of columns
maxLength <- max(sapply(y,length))
# pad each list element with empty strings
z <- lapply(y, function(x) c(x,rep("",maxLength-length(x))))
# create final matrix
out <- do.call(rbind, z)
```

Update:

Here's another solution using `plyr::rbind.fill`:

```
x <- readLines("foo.txt")  # read data with readLines
nx <- !nchar(x)            # locate lines with only empty strings
# create final data.frame
out <- rbind.fill(lapply(split(x[!nx], cumsum(nx)[!nx]),
                    function(x) data.frame(t(x))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Another strategy is to use a string of your choosing -- call it `EOL` -- to mark the end of each line, and then paste all of the lines together.

You can then use two rounds of `strsplit` to **first** break out records, and **then** break out fields within records.  (Records will be separated by two consecutive `EOL`s, while fields will be separated by a single `EOL`).

```
EOL <- "!@"  # (for instance)
x <- readLines("filename.R")
x <- paste(x, collapse=EOL)[[1]]

x <- strsplit(x, paste(EOL, EOL, sep=""))         # Split apart records
lapply(x, FUN=function(X) strsplit(X, EOL))[[1]]  # Split apart fields w/in records
```

This method appeals to me because it's close to what I'd *like* to do when I read in the file in the first place (i.e. use `"\n\n"` as the `sep` character), but am not able to do with either `scan` or `readLines`.

Answer (score 2):

Read data in.
    dat <- readLines("filename.txt")

Split data by records (inspired by Josh O'Brien solution)

```
dat_rec <- lapply(strsplit(paste(dat,collapse="\n"),split="\n\n")[[1]],
                  function(x) strsplit(x,split="\n")[[1]])
```

Transform data to named vectors (assume last field is comment and data starts with numeric value)

```
dat_rec_vn <- lapply(dat_rec,function(x) {
                           vn <- gsub(" ","_",sub("  ","",
                                        gsub("^(\\D*) \\d.*$","\\1", x[-length(x)])))
                           y <- gsub("^(\\D*) (\\d.*)$","\\2",x[-length(x)])
                           names(y) <- vn
                           return(y)})
```

Get unique names of field in data.

```
 vn <- unique(unlist(lapply(dat_rec_vn,names),use.names=FALSE))
```

Combine field into matrix and give it names.

```
 dat_mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(dat_rec_vn,function(x) {
                     y <- vector(mode="character",length=length(vn))
                     y[match(names(x),vn)] <- x
                     return(y)}))

colnames(dat_mat) <- vn
```

SECOND solution (using gawk)

```
gawk_cmd <- "gawk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\\n\";RS=\"\";OFS=\"\\t\";ORS=\"\\n\"} 
                        {$1=$1; print $0}' test_multi.txt"
dat <- strsplit(system(gawk_cmd,intern=TRUE),split="\t")
NF <- do.call(max,lapply(dat,length))
M <- do.call(rbind,lapply(dat,"[",seq(NF)))
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the `[[1]]` is doing in the first line?

Comment: strsplit returns list of vectors for each element of character vector (even for character vector of length one). We need first element on this list so [[1]] is used to get it. The same function is used on second line.

Comment: Oh, so would that be a way to vectorise a list as long as one only wanted the first element?