# Extract tables from a single file

Tags: r

I am trying to extract multiple tables from a single file in R. My file contains tables with the same number of variables but with a variable number of records. I would like to extract only the tables (numbers) and transfer these into separate files. Between tables there are 4 lines (blank line, run: nr, variable names, units) that I would like to get rid off. The alternative to break at each blank line is also a good solution for me but I have not managed to do this either. Below I provide and example of file - my real files contain multiple runs (tables) with each more than 30 variables and 150-300 records. 
Many thanks for your help!

Example:

```
> data <- readLines(textConnection("
              + MODEL OUTPUT
              +
              + Run: 1
              + V1  V2 V3
              +        mm
              + 20  2  2.0
              + 21  2  1.5
              + 22  2  3.5
              +
              + Run: 2
              + V1 V2 V3
              +       mm
              + 1  1  1.5
              + 2  1  2.5
              +
              + Run: 3
              + V1 V2 V3
              +       mm
              + 11  5  1.5
              + 12  5  2.5                                
              + 13  5  1.0
              + 14  5  4.5"))
```

Comment: I think [How do I read a text file into R when each record is a paragraph and some records have 4 fields and others have 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452473/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-r-when-each-record-is-a-paragraph-and-some-record) should get you going.

Comment: Also related: [*"extract data between a pattern from a text file in R"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663246/extract-data-between-a-pattern-from-a-text-file-in-r) and [*"R convert unstructured csv file to a data frame"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719058/r-convert-unstructured-csv-file-to-a-data-frame)

Comment: Several on the [`readLines` - `cumsum` - `split` theme](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20readLines%20cumsum%20split). Choose your dupe ;) Good luck!

Comment: `L <- lapply(split(data, cumsum(data == ""))[-1], function(x) read.table(text = x[-c(1, 2, 4)], header = TRUE));
names(L) <- grep("Run", data, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Do you have control over how this output is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we aren't marking this a duplicate, I'll answer. You can handle this with a bit of pre-processing, then `cumsum` to enumerate contiguous sections of the text, and finally `read.table` to read these sections as tables.

Create example data:

```
file_text <- readLines(textConnection("
    + MODEL OUTPUT
    +
      + Run: 1
    + V1  V2 V3
    +        mm
    + 20  2  2.0
    + 21  2  1.5
    + 22  2  3.5
    +
      + Run: 2
    + V1 V2 V3
    +       mm
    + 1  1  1.5
    + 2  1  2.5
    +
      + Run: 3
    + V1 V2 V3
    +       mm
    + 11  5  1.5
    + 12  5  2.5                                
    + 13  5  1.0
    + 14  5  4.5"))
```

Preprocess: eliminate `MODEL OUTPUT`, leading `+`, and the lines with only `mm`.

```
file_text = file_text[!grepl('MODEL OUTPUT', file_text)]
file_text = file_text[!grepl('Run: \\d+', file_text)]
file_text = sapply(file_text, sub, pattern = "^\\s*\\+", replacement = "")
file_text = file_text[!grepl('^\\s*mm\\s*$', file_text)]
```

Identify empty lines - call these the breaks between sections - and then number the lines by section.

```
is_break = unname(sapply(file_text, function(x) trimws(x) == ""))
section_id = unname(cumsum(is_break))
section_id
#  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Finally split up the file text into sections and read those as tables:

```
tabs = lapply(unique(section_id), function(i) {
  # the first line of a section will always be empty
  section_lines = file_text[section_id == i][-1]
  if (length(section_lines)) {
    # there's a section of text
    read.table(text = section_lines, header = TRUE)
  } else {
    # there were two consecutive section breaks, so after the first break
    # there's an empty 'section'
    NA
  }
})
```

The result is a list of data.frames. Handle the missing tables now or earlier, as you like.

```
tabs
# [[1]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[2]]
#   V1 V2  V3
# 1 20  2 2.0
# 2 21  2 1.5
# 3 22  2 3.5
# 
# [[3]]
#   V1 V2  V3
# 1  1  1 1.5
# 2  2  1 2.5
# 
# [[4]]
#   V1 V2  V3
# 1 11  5 1.5
# 2 12  5 2.5
# 3 13  5 1.0
# 4 14  5 4.5
#
```

Comment: Your suggested solutions worked and I learned new tricks. Thank you!